# tengo una consulta desde NodeJS a MySql

Tags: mysql, nodejs

el problema es el siguiente, en mi archivo .js con NodeJs uso la libreria mysql y cuando hago la consulta

```
connection.query(`INSERT INTO ${tabla} (nombre,dni,curso,telefono,email,tipo) VALUES (${nombre},${dni},${curso},${telefono},${email},${tipo})
```

lo exporto normal al modulo pero cuando ingreso el mail me dice:

> Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com,admin)' at line 1

Comment: ¿Seguro que así tienes la consulta? Por qué no pruebas yendo a [edit] y añadiendo algunas líneas más para ver qué es connection y esas cosas?

Comment: Lo mas probable es que te falten las comillas para los campos de tipo `varchar` por ejemplo `... VALUES("${nombre}", ...`